# .NET Core project can't call .NET 4.6 class library method which uses NTLM

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 project that is using AutoFAC for DI. I have a class library project in the solution which is running .NET Framework 4.6. I'm consuming a wsdl from an endpoint that requires specific NTLM authentication credentials to be passed. In a standalone .NET 4.6 project my code works, but when I called the .NET 4.6 project method from the .NET Core 2.1 code, I'm getting the following error:

```
Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused.

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(HttpRequestException requestException, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsync(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsyncInternal(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task`1 task)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
at generatedProxy_1.SO(SORequest )
at PM.xpSvc.xpWSSoapClient.PM.xpSvc.xpWSSoap.SO(SORequest request)
at PM.xpSvc.xpWSSoapClient.SO(IPackets pPacketsIn)
at PM.Services.xpService.CreditCardSubmitPayment(CreditCardSubmitPaymentRequestModel request)
```

Here is some of the code in the .NET 4.6 method that passes the NTLM auth to the endpoint:

```
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://secret.com/ws.asmx");
BasicHttpsBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;

var xpService = new xpWSSoapClient(myBinding, myEndpoint);
xpService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain =   "domain";
xpService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user";
xpService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pass";

response = xpService.SO(requestModelHere);
```

I had gotten this request to work if I added this just before the call:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

However, it causes the rest of the .NET Core project to not function properly with other calls. Are there any other ways to make this work without pulling this project out of the solution and making it a stand-alone service?

Comment: Cause .Net4.6 class library dll is not portable and can't be used

Comment: NTLM is Windows specific.. you cannot use it in cross-platform .NET Core apps

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this in .NET Core 2.1 code? I tried to use ConfigureServices (ISerivceCollection services) { ... } but maybe my implementation was not correct.

Comment: Try the workaround from [https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2923](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2923#issuecomment-480689670)

Comment: It is fixed in 2.2.7 or 2.1.13